# FlutterFlow: Cupertino Datepicker

Tags: flutterflow, custom-code

i want to add a cupertino (ios style) timepicker to flutterflow which will let the user pick the hour and minutes.

I've tried making it myself but didn't get anywhere with the small amount of experience and knowledge i found on internet.

All that's left is try a custom widget but i have no idea how to use it and neither the experience to create something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for something exacly this moment and I found this solution: https://community.flutterflow.io/custom-code/post/how-to-see-widget-state-from-custom-widget-cupertinodatepicker-1rJsnWeFQ2PqyKI

in FlutterFlow you will need create a new Custom Widget to implemention libary cupertino

Comment: Please review, [edit] and try for [answer]. You might also want to take the recommended [tour].